# How to position an absolute element right under his relative parent if its height is dynamic?

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have the following code:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
.child {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">asdasdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to position the absolutely positioned child element right under its parent, which means it is supposed to go out of the parent's box model. This has to work even if the child doesn't have a defined height.

Comment: top:100% ? ....

Comment: Top:100% if the parent is in position relative/absolute/fixed or sticky but not static.

Comment: Oh so simple, thanks fellas!